# Jquery on span text change

Tags: jquery

I have    `<span id="row">text</span>`, text inside is changing by another function.

Can I make event 'on this text change'?
like

> `$('#row').text().change(function(){ /some action... });`

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly like following:

```
$('#row').change(function(){
    //some action
});
```

Comment: Can you give me link/example,because i have never used `.change()` this way for a div/span. @WisdmLabs

Comment: You just need to trigger change.

Comment: Eg: $('#row')..html('demo").trigger('change'); This will trigger change on span.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the old HTML of the div in a variable. 
Also,use an setInterval of maybe 1 second,to check if the old content is same as current. When this isn't true do something.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function: `$("#row").on("change", function() { ... });`